# SAT based motion planning

Tags: sat, motion-planning

```
              SAT BASED MOTION PLANNING ALGORITHM
```

A simple **motion planning problem** can be remodelled as a **SAT solving problem**. Can anyone explain how is this possible?

In this problem, we have to find a collision free path from start to end location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example could look like this.

Let's introduce 2D grid of N rows and M columns, a moving agent A starts at a node (x,y). His target T has coordinates (x_i, y_j):

[image: a grid]

To reach a target the agent should perform several steps - move left, right, up or down consequently. We don't know how many steps it needs, so we have to limit this number ourselves. Let's say, we are searching for a plan that consists of K steps. In this case, we should add N*M*K boolean variables: N and M represent coordinates, K - time. If a variable is **True** then the agent currently at a node (**x**,**y**) at time **k**.

Next, we add various constraints:

1. The agent **must** change his position at each step (this is optional, actually)
2. If robot at step **k** is at a position (x,y), then at step **k+1** it must be at one of four adjacent nodes
3. SAT formula is satisfied if and only if the agent at step **k** is at the target node

I'll not discuss a detailed implementation of the constraints here, it's  not that difficult. The similar approach could be used for [multiagent planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-agent_planning).

This example is just an illustration. People use [satplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satplan) and [STRIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STRIPS) in real life.

EDIT1
In the case of a collision-free path you should add additional constraints:

1. If a node contains an obstacle, an agent can't visit it. E.g. corresponding boolean variables can't be **True** at any timestep e.g. it's always **False**
2. If we are talking about a multiagent system, then two boolean variables, corresponding to two agents being at same timestep at the same node, can't be **True** simultaneously:

`AND (agent1_x_y_t, agent2_x_y_t) <=> False`

EDIT2

How to build a formula that would be satisfied. Iterate over all nodes and all timestamps, e.g. over each Boolean variable. For each Boolean variable add constraints (I'll use Python-like pseudocode):

```
 formula = []
 for x in range(N):
     for y in range(M):
         for t in range (K):
             current_var = all_vars[x][y][t]
             # obstacle
             if obstacle:
                 formula = AND (formula, NOT (current_var))

             # an agent should change his location each step
             prev_step = get_prev_step (x,y,t)
             change = NOT (AND (current_var, prev_step))
             formula = AND (formula, change)

             adjacent_nodes = get_adj (x,y, k+1)

             constr = AND (current_var, only_one_is_true (adjacent_nodes))
             formula = AND (formula, constr)
 satisfy (formula)
```

Comment: I am sorry I should have explicitly mentioned about the problem. 
Can your solution be modified in any way to satisfy the constraints?

Comment: @JaskiratSingh You can add any constraints you want to this task, I've tried to introduce the basic constraints and the way to look at this problem.

Comment: Yeah , got it . Thanks :)